# Panic error при старте докера

Tags: docker

После перезагрузки сервера и запуска doсker'a, запустился docker-client, а вот docker-server падает с

```
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Версия докера:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:11:02 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Логи:

```
    systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process" pid=8969
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42007f850, CONNECTING" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587 version=v1.1.1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.sna
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snaps
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshott
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Start cri plugin with config {PluginConfig:{ContainerdConfig:{Snapshotter:overlayfs DefaultRuntime:{Type:io.containerd.runti
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Connect containerd service"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Get image filesystem path "/var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs""
dockerd[8957]:  level=error msg="Failed to load cni during init, please check CRI plugin status before setting up network for pods" error="cni config load f
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Start subscribing containerd event"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Start recovering state"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.004553s"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Start event monitor"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Start snapshots syncer"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Start streaming server"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42007f850, READY" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42022e6b0, CONNECTING" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42022e6b0, READY" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: aufs"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42007fb10, CONNECTING" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42007fb10, READY" module=grpc
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
dockerd[8957]:  level=error msg="Error looking up volumes-from container" error="No such container: nginx_tmp" from-container=nginx_tmp
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 2d1a1a359b706b431d238879c8058896674d024900c904fd3bd042be88a59aea (9e8e0a015e130064c8d6dafef
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 2facfc4a7575cdd1068191b89f9bb5be51886b79cede08d9f086e97a8a33713f (c55ea4de191bed702751d1d2f
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 8b26968ea28f5b8d02bec9110f7bdc31bdb86bbdd58cb84c4bb8a86a72959168 (15451828b6862127483479f4d
dockerd[8957]:  level=error msg="getNetworkFromStore for nid 24c07b727fcd9a26b55d2fabeea15ed4180635993e01d785f96e98586f7d4826 failed while trying 
dockerd[8957]:  level=error msg="getEndpointFromStore for eid ec4ce27ba19489124e9e94d0350cb6b4ca436373f365ffb5a1cfeddfaf8693b4 failed while trying
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox cdfce5c36c9319e04d78f8d729a26e93514b8ce09dc112cc95e1a9b51eb91147 (ae73cb3f0eed4c1fe5dcd4dae
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint aa663d95d46313623107d8a798d
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Failed getting network for ep 6908fe3dbfa7e246943d23a0d997cdaa0767c30b33366626733f2c765ed06fb1 during sandbox c
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Failed deleting endpoint ec4ce27ba19489124e9e94d0350cb6b4ca436373f365ffb5a1cfeddfaf8693b4: failed to get endpoi
dockerd[8957]:  level=error msg="Failed to delete sandbox cdfce5c36c9319e04d78f8d729a26e93514b8ce09dc112cc95e1a9b51eb91147 while trying to cleanup
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Removing stale endpoint labgate-classifier-workers (7b841784d865d6f6e2a647a7311b2198d9246e6c40e3568ac701af15cb1996
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Fixing inconsistent endpoint_cnt for network labgate. Expected=0, Actual=2"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Removing stale endpoint labgate_meteor (00dd85a246fa4bf1279f19afb4a8e0424c607bda84fd81a40b9c3e37c41ebb39)"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Fixing inconsistent endpoint_cnt for network bridge. Expected=0, Actual=1"
dockerd[8957]:  level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a pr
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Failed getting network for ep 6908fe3dbfa7e246943d23a0d997cdaa0767c30b33366626733f2c765ed06fb1 during sandbox c
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Failed detaching sandbox cdfce5c36c9319e04d78f8d729a26e93514b8ce09dc112cc95e1a9b51eb91147 from endpoint ec4ce27
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Failed deleting endpoint ec4ce27ba19489124e9e94d0350cb6b4ca436373f365ffb5a1cfeddfaf8693b4: failed to get endpoi
dockerd[8957]:  level=error msg="failed to cleanup up stale network sandbox for container ae73cb3f0eed4c1fe5dcd4dae9cc9106fbfaa66101938c5663e89fcf
dockerd[8957]:  level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 9003-9003: Bind for 127.0.0.1:9003 failed: port is already allocated"
dockerd[8957]:  level=error msg="9e8e0a015e130064c8d6dafefce869033feccacc299c3d55a05c93366fe2794a cleanup: failed to delete container from contain
dockerd[8957]:  level=error msg="Failed to start container 9e8e0a015e130064c8d6dafefce869033feccacc299c3d55a05c93366fe2794a: driver failed program
dockerd[8957]: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
dockerd[8957]: [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x56278d414055]
goroutine 307 [running]:
dockerd[8957]: github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/libnetwork.(*endpoint).addServiceInfoToCluster(0xc42025ef20, 0xc4201cb000, 0x0, 0x0)
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/libnetwork/agent.go:586 +0xa5
dockerd[8957]: github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/libnetwork.(*sandbox).EnableService(0xc4201cb000, 0x0, 0x0)
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/libnetwork/sandbox.go:701 +0x16f
dockerd[8957]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).ActivateContainerServiceBinding(0xc4203aac40, 0xc4201f1970, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0)
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/container_operations.go:1118 +0x89
dockerd[8957]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).connectToNetwork(0xc4203aac40, 0xc4201c6b40, 0x56278da5ab44, 0x6, 0xc420562300, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/container_operations.go:796 +0x9db
dockerd[8957]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).allocateNetwork(0xc4203aac40, 0xc4201c6b40, 0x0, 0x0)
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/container_operations.go:540 +0xa31
dockerd[8957]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).initializeNetworking(0xc4203aac40, 0xc4201c6b40, 0x0, 0x0)
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/container_operations.go:953 +0xa2
dockerd[8957]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).containerStart(0xc4203aac40, 0xc4201c6b40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/start.go:150 +0x2c2
dockerd[8957]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).restore.func2(0xc420c3be10, 0xc4203aac40, 0xc4206cec00, 0xc4201c6b40, 0xc4202c6cc0)
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:388 +0x2d4
dockerd[8957]: created by github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).restore
dockerd[8957]:         /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:368 +0x1025
systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Ошибка началась не на этой версии докера, но после обновления ничего не изменилось.

Если переименовать `/var/lib/docker/aufs` - то докер запускает, но без контейнеров.

Comment: думаю стоит завести дефект у них на гитхабе

Comment: @Mikhail попробуйте так  - создайте фал /etc/docker/daemon.json с содержимым {    "storage-driver": "overlay2" } и перезапустите докер сервис - systemctl restart docker. Потом заново поднимете свой контейнер